# Is there a way to test if someone has said something in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is make a command that allows me to say something like "home" in the chat, and have a command block teleport me to my house. Is there a way to test for a word in chat?

Comment: No, but you could use book and quills. I once made a system that detected players who had written commands in books and quills, and when they had, they had something execute at them. It's currently in one of my singleplayer worlds, but I'm not able to access them at the moment. If you give me a few days, I can send you the world, or the commands I used. (By the way, one command I had set up was /home.)

Comment: One way to monitor chat is to have "choose-your-adventure" format, ie made with `/tellraw` commands that have a click event which causes the player to choose what they say, and control functioal reactions by setting `clickEvent` areas to place redstone blocks in a possibly remote system.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot test for what someone has *said* in chat. You could however set up your own custom `/trigger` commands.

You can do this by first creating a "trigger" type scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add home trigger
```

Then enable it for whoever you want to be able to use it:

```
/scoreboard players enable @a home
```

Any player who has it enabled, even non-OPs, can now use `/trigger home set` or `/trigger home add` to manipulate their "home" scoreboard objective.

You can add a `/tp @a[score_home_min=1] X Y Z` on a clock to have it so anyone who does `/trigger home set 1` in chat is teleported home. Follow it up with setting their home score back to 1, so they aren't constantly teleported, and re-enable the objective for them, so they can use it again.

Comment: Sorry if I missed something, but how does this test if the player is saying something in chat?

Comment: @tuxedoandex It tests if the player types `/trigger home` into chat. It won't appear in chat for other players as it's a command, but appearing in chat for other players to see does not seem to be a requirement for OP's question. It's more of a workaround than *exactly* what was wanted, but it should still work.

Comment: THIS CHANGES EVERYTHING! you could make reformatted commands so typing "/trigger spawn" would teleport you to spawn, thus bypassing the needs for plugins! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 7):

**Not in vanilla Minecraft, no**. There is no way in vanilla Minecraft on a vanilla server to implement any sort of custom chat commands, or detect any sort of chat events.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, if you're using the home functionality, you might also want to repeat the steps above to create a sethome trigger, then use a command to set an armorstand there with a unique name.

See [How to enable home / sethome on a Vanilla Minecraft Server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223444/how-to-enable-sethome-and-home-on-a-vanilla-minecraft-server)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible to `/testfor` if someone is saying something in chat but you need plugins (`/testforchat`). Then you put in any text that you want the player to say and then you can mess around with it.

Comment: What plugin is this exactly?