# How to enable sethome and home on a Vanilla Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've seen some Vanilla Minecraft servers that use books with a teleport home, set home, and tp to spawn options. I found an app that I can use to build the custom book, but I can't figure out how to allow players to set home, automatically get books when they die/first spawn, etc. Is there somewhere with some good tutorials for doing this in vanilla, or does anybody know how to get this to work?

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djN0r1c3cgI), and I even downloaded the world to try and test it out. It works okay in the downloaded world, but I can't reproduce it in my world. The main issue, I think, is I can't figure out how the command blocks/glowstone lamps are being powered. If I could see the wiring behind things, I could maybe reproduce it.

I can't seem to find a lot out there on this. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to activate the commands is as follows:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~2 ~ {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~2 ~-1 ~2 ~-2 ~4 ~14 minecraft:stained_glass 0 hollow",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~2 ~-2 ~2 ~-2 ~-2 ~14 minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 4",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~1 ~-2 ~3 ~-1 ~4 ~13 air",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~1 ~-3 ~12 ~-1 ~0 ~12 redstone_block",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"summon FallingSand ~-1 ~3 ~11 {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"/gamerule commandBlockOutput false\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"/gamerule logAdminCommands false\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard objectives add mayGoHome dummy\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"iron_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"summon FallingSand ~-1 ~2 ~13 {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard objectives add maySetHome dummy\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard players set @a maySetHome 1\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard players set @a mayGoHome 1\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"iron_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"summon FallingSand ~0 ~1 ~11 {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard objectives add home trigger\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"tellraw @a[score_home_min=1] {\\\"text\\\":\\\"Gone Home\\\", color:\\\"gold\\\"}\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard objectives add sethome trigger\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"iron_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"summon FallingSand ~0 ~0 ~13 {Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"fill ~-2 ~4 ~1 ~2 ~4 ~-11 minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 4\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"summon FallingSand ~0 ~1 ~-10 {id:\\\"FallingSand\\\",Block:\\\"redstone_block\\\",Time:1}\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"iron_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/summon FallingSand ~-1 ~2 ~3 {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"/fill ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~3 ~7 stone\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a ~ ~ ~ trigger sethome set 0\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a[score_sethome_min=1] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Home]\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"tellraw @a[score_sethome_min=1] {\\\"text\\\":\\\"Home Set\\\", color:\\\"gold\\\"}\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/summon FallingSand ~1 ~1 ~3 {Riding:{Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"/fill ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~3 ~7 redstone_block\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard players enable @a[score_maySetHome_min=1] sethome\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a[score_sethome_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomName:Home,Invulnerable:1b}\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a[score_sethome_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Home] @p\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/summon FallingSand ~-1 ~0 ~4 {Riding:{Riding:{TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a ~ ~ ~ trigger home set 0\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"scoreboard players enable @a[score_mayGoHome_min=1] home\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:\"execute @a[score_home_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @p @e[name=Home]\",id:\"Control\"},id:\"FallingSand\",Block:\"command_block\",Time:1}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock ~ ~-8 ~1 wall_sign 2 0 {Text1:\"===============\",Text2:\"{text:\\\"Click\\\",color:\\\"dark_red\\\",clickEvent:{action:run_command,value:\\\"/fill ~2 ~1 ~ ~-2 ~-4 ~13 air\\\"},extra:[{text:\\\" to remove\\\",color:\\\"black\\\"}]}\",Text3:\"this structure\",Text4:\"===============\"}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock ~ ~-10 ~1 wall_sign 2 0 {Text2:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"May\\\"}\",Text3:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"Set Home\\\"}\",Text1:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"clickEvent\\\":{\\\"action\\\":\\\"run_command\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"/scoreboard players set @a maySetHome 1\\\"},\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",Text4:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",y:52,x:20,z:-1,id:\"Sign\"}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock ~ ~-12 ~1 wall_sign 2 0 {Text2:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"May Not\\\"}\",Text3:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"Set Home\\\"}\",Text1:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"clickEvent\\\":{\\\"action\\\":\\\"run_command\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"/scoreboard players set @p maySetHome 0\\\"},\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",Text4:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",y:52,x:22,z:-1,id:\"Sign\"}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock ~ ~-14 ~1 wall_sign 2 0 {Text2:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"May\\\"}\",Text3:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"Go Home\\\"}\",Text1:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"clickEvent\\\":{\\\"action\\\":\\\"run_command\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"/scoreboard players set @p mayGoHome 1\\\"},\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",Text4:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",y:52,x:24,z:-1,id:\"Sign\"}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock ~ ~-16 ~1 wall_sign 2 0 {Text2:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"May Not\\\"}\",Text3:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"Go Home\\\"}\",Text1:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"clickEvent\\\":{\\\"action\\\":\\\"run_command\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"/scoreboard players set @p mayGoHome 0\\\"},\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",Text4:\"{\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\"}\",y:52,x:25,z:-1,id:\"Sign\"}",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~ ~-16 ~ ~-1 ~2 ~ air",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~-1 ~-17 ~ ~-1 ~-1 ~ redstone_block",id:"Control"},id:"FallingSand",Block:"command_block",Time:1},id:"FallingSand",Block:"redstone_block",Time:1}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much! Is there a standard way of handling say giving someone a server book on 1st spawn/respawn / teleporting someone to a spawnpoint or home depending on whether they died or are joining the server for the first time?

Comment: @theBreaks I'll try to work out a design for that, but am not sure as of current.

Comment: This command is badly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

For the first spawn you'll have to make a scoreboard objective (call it what you like) and then there is a command that goes something like this (don't <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>c</kbd> it it wont work is just goes something like this...)

```
/testfor @p[maximum_scorebored_objective_{objective name}=0]
```

You then hook that up to some redstone and another command block which gives them the stuff you want to give them when they first spawn.

Good luck!